# Page load issue with GA4

Tags: google-analytics, pageload, google-analytics-4, page-load-time

We have a problem related to execution times are observed related to GA4:

Basically, the page loads so fast that once an action is signalled and, in most cases, GA4 does not have time to execute. We did not see this problem with UA.

With 'Preview Mode'in GTM, GA4 executes as it should do, and so, the information is sent to GA4 servers.

About the "normal" execution: the website behaves way too fast, and so, even though GA4 executes, it does not have enough time to send the information to GA4 servers (pending requests which information does never reach GA4 servers).

We investigated and tested different implementation ways to fix it but the problem is still there.

Any of you have an idea about this?

We also attach the screenshots of the tests carried out:

UA run times, approx. 100-200 ms. - [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnDZ9.jpg)

GA4 runtimes, approx. 5 seconds - [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kv6VR.jpg)

GA4 execution times with the GA Debug extension activated, approx. 100-200 ms. - [Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i79Zj.jpg)

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Do you still see the issue between UA and GA4?

Based on the google document from GA4, GA4 will use `sendBeacon` to send events, this is to fix some problems with the old UA using `XMLHttpRequest` to send events, the problem with the `XMLHttpRequest` is that if events send during the unload page event, the events might not send by the browser.

Also, depending on the scenarios, most GA4 events will batch together and send from the browser, so if you're in debugging mode, events are sent immediately, that's why you see the time faster.

So, in normal mode, GA4 might send events in delay but it batch events altogher, the good thing is if you go to a different page, the event will continue to fire sine GA4 using the `sendBeacon` API.

You can also refer to this [article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9964640?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) from GA4 about event batching for GA4.